# Instantiating a PHP class using a variable is not working

Tags: php, class, instantiation

This is working:

```
$x = new classname();
```

This is not working:

```
$class = "classname";
$x = new $class();
```

The error I get is "Class classname not found". PHP version is 5.4.22. Any ideas? As far as I have researched into this topic this is exactly what you need to do in order to instantiate a class using a variable.

My actual testcode (copy+paste), $build = 1:

```
//include the update file
$class="db_update_" . str_pad($build, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
require_once(__ROOT__ . "/dbupdates/" . $class . ".php");

$x = new db_update_0001();
$xyz="db_update_0001";
$x = new $xyz();
```

The class definition:

```
namespace dbupdates;

require_once("db_update.php");

class db_update_0001 extends db_update
{
...
}
```

I just found out that my editor added

```
use dbupdates\db_update_0001;
```

to the file. So that explains why "new db_update_0001();" is working. What i want to achieve is that I dynamically include database updates which are stored in files like dbupdates/db_update_0001.php

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Well then there is no definition for class `classname`. Show us the definition and where and how you include it.

Comment: Works for me... [**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.org/GduAZoel)

Comment: This works for me: $c = "stdClass"; $x = new $c();

Comment: I added some more informations. HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the full qualified class name. Which is `namespace\classname`. So in your case the code should be:

```
$x = new db_update_0001();
$xyz="dbupdates\db_update_0001";
$x = new $xyz();
```

The `use` statement is useless if you like to instantiate a class by using a variable as classname.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<?php
$className = yourClassName();
$x = new $className;
?>
```

Comment: Given the lack of any function called `yourClassName()` what do you expect this to achieve besides erroring?